# "Try Ubuntu" crashes in 18.04 live cd

Tags: boot, 18.04, ubiquity

I'm trying to run a live version of Ubuntu 18.04 but as soon as I click on "Try Ubuntu" the mouse' cursor disappears and the system gets stuck.

I tryed to click install and then exit, I was able to move the window and I saw a standard "ubuntu has experienced an internal error", but as I click continue another popup appears, telling me a live desktop would be launched and then the system gets stuck like before.

My clevo P640RE laptop:

- i7-6700HQ
- 8GB ram
- Nvidia GeForce GTX 970M
- Intel Wireless 8260

Comment: Maybe the [boot option](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808) `nomodeset` will help with the nvidia graphics card. If you get it working this way, you can try later to install a proprietary nvidia graphics driver to use the full power of the graphics card.

Comment: Thanks @sudodus, i achieved booting live with `nomodeset`. How this could impact my system once i install it?

Comment: You can use `nomodeset` also in the installed system. And later on try a proprietary nvidia graphics driver. You can keep  `nomodeset` in your installed system. See [Grub2/Setup](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup). -- `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`  Entries on this line are added to the end of the 'linux' command line (GRUB legacy's "kernel" line) for both normal and recovery modes. It is used to pass options to the kernel.

Comment: You are welcome and good luck :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved this issue thanks to @sudodus.
For others with the same problem, while booting Ubuntu 18.04 press `F6`. 
A menu will appear with different options, pressing `F6` and `e` you could edit the boot options, just add `nomodeset` before `quiet splash` and press enter.

Once installed you can install proprietary drivers to use the dedicated graphic card.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution :-) You can click on the tick symbol to 'accept' the answer (self-answering is OK when there is no good answer by someone else and in this case there are only the short comments from me). It will indicate for other people, that there is a good answer to this particular question.

Comment: Actually it's your ahahha

Comment: @DanieleGamba but you can still click your answer after a couple of days to accept it. It helps other readers know what works.

Comment: Linux users have long had a love-hate relationship with Nvidia. Linus Torvalds literally gave it the middle finger a few years ago. Torvalds also called them “the single worst company” the Linux developer community has ever had to deal with.