# Dual boot on laptop

Tags: dual-boot, laptop

Any Linux gurus out there? I am trying to dual boot Ubuntu Linux on my Acer Aspire E15 laptop.  I have already disabled secure boot with nothing but a black screen after the install Ubuntu selection. I have also tried Legacy boot mode instead of UEFI, with different results. I get to the same install Ubuntu Linux selection with a different UI but in this case I get a white flashing cursor on the top left instead of a black screen. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you detail a little better what do you do and where the system stucks? Do you have discrete graphics?

Comment: I  shrunk my windows 10 volume by 20gb so I would have room for this installation.  I tried this USB installer on a desktop and it worked fine.  It does have dedicated nvidia graphics as well, Idk if that matters.

Comment: Please refer to the answer you find [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029127/try-ubuntu-crashes-in-18-04-live-cd) to use `nomodeset` boot option and tell me if it works.

Comment: See these also: Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot and 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/870022/how-to-get-grub-boot-option/870074